# Pocketsphinx Decoder.hyp does not return a Hypothesis object

Tags: python, speech-recognition, attributeerror, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am programming a speech to text decoder with pocketsphinx.

The program runs properly but when I try to do keyword spotting an error occurs.

The problem seems to be in the final print, when I try to get `hypstr`.

I get the error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hypstr'
```

How can I fix it?

```
# Decoder config
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'es/es'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'voxforge_es_sphinx.dic'))
config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'es-20k.lm'))
#config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'escucha')
#config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)
#config.set_string('-jsgf', GRAMMAR)
decoder = Decoder(config)
#decoder.set_jsgf_file('grammar', GRAMMAR)
decoder.set_keyphrase('keyphrase', 'escucha')
decoder.set_search('keyphrase')

# Pyaudio config
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024, exception_on_overflow = False)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()

                #Print hypothesis
                print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr

                if decoder.get_search() == 'keyphrase':
                    decoder.set_search('lm')
                else:
                    decoder.set_search('keyphrase')

                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

### Error Traceback:

```
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 55041
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 233 root, 54913 non-root channels, 30 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: kws_search.c(406): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold 0, delay 10)
INFO: cmn_live.c(120): Update from < 40.00  3.00 -1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 >
INFO: cmn_live.c(138): Update to   < 25.82 -4.30 -6.09  0.55 -2.52 -1.35  1.77 -1.72 -2.17  0.29  0.35 -2.03 -0.39 >
INFO: kws_search.c(656): kws 0.20 CPU 0.048 xRT
INFO: kws_search.c(658): kws 4.35 wall 1.055 xRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/tonydelalg/PycharmProjects/untitled/markdown.py", line 43, in <module>
    print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
Result:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hypstr'
INFO: kws_search.c(448): TOTAL kws 0.20 CPU 0.048 xRT
INFO: kws_search.c(451): TOTAL kws 4.35 wall 1.058 xRT
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot. There are other useful information -ie. which line of code makes problem.

Comment: it seams `decoder.hyp()` gives `None` so you can't use `decoder.hyp().hypstr` because it means `None.hypstr`. Now you have to read documentation why `decoder.hyp()` gives `None`

Comment: try saving decoder.hyp() to a variable `temp`, then call `temp.hypstr()`

Comment: @furas I read the `__doc__` for `decoder.hyp()` and it should be yielding a `pocketsphinx.Hypothesis` object, not a `None`.

Comment: @JakobLovern saving variable doesn't work

Comment: I'm going to try with an try/except AttributeError, It maybe fix it.

Comment: None is expected result from hyp(), it means nothing is recognized. You need to check for None before accessing hypstr.